# Allow users to edit PDF documents on IPAD

Tags: html, ipad, iframe

My application basically has list of PDF forms and it allows the end users to fill up the forms(Edit forms) and that will be send back to server.
This application is an ipad application It works fine on desktop.But when i launch that application in ipad , PDF opens only with text and does not show any PDF fields (like radio buttons ,Checkbox and PDF submit button which are created using Acrobat). and there is no way to edit PDF forms in ipad(This form is displayed in an Iframe).

Ipad's browser has its built in PDF viewer which will not allow users to edit forms. Is there any plugin which i can use for this purpose ? or there are many app on appstore for editing PDF on IPad. So is there a way to integrate that app in our application ?

How do i achieve this ?

Comment: i found an interesting link http://wordpress.findfollowtweet.com/20-free-tools-to-annotate-pdf-documents/

Comment: @Rachel Gallen : Thanks for your reply. I checked out the above link. Those all are app from appstore. How do i integrate native apps with my application ?

Comment: oh i don't know i'll have a look for some opensource apps

Comment: Consider PSPDFKit as a commercial solution, It fully supports PDF AcroForm filling, and it uses WebAssembly for high performance. https://pspdfkit.com/guides/web/current/migration-guides/migrating-from-mozilla-pdfjs/

Answer (score 0):

You could try out [PDF.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js), [pdfedit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfedit) or [pdfstudio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF_Studio). [Xournal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xournal) also supports annotations. These are all opensource.

Comment: Can i have iframe with PDF.js ?

Comment: PDF.js is currently only a PDF reader (renderer), as stated by their README. Can i use PDF.js to Edit PDF document displayed in an iframe ?

Comment: I haven't used that. Have you tried pdfedit?  It's recommended on wikipedia.